# Regex matching first capital letter followed by one or more small letters

Tags: java, regex

That is my regular expression:

```
[A-Ö]{1}[a-ö]
```

When I write that everything is fine until I write another small letter it doesn't work. E.g. `Ab` works, but `Cmo` or `Klfdklgklhsh` don't work. How can I do this?

*EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS*:

If I use `[A-Ö]{1}[a-ö]+` then it also supports `ab`, `klofn` and `nnn` for example. I need for the first letter to be only a capital letter.

Comment: @stribizhev it says more than one small leter

Comment: The limniting quantifier is redundant, `{1}` can be removed. What are your actual requirements? `[A-Ö]` matches all lower and uppercase letters and a lot of other symbols, too. I feel you need `[A-ZÖ][a-zö]+`

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman If I do that then it also supports ab, klofn and nnn for example. I need for the first letter to be only a capital letter.

Comment: I'm using a program that my teacher made and if I write [A-Z][a-z]+ then It accepts ab. I need Ab and small letters after b.

Comment: @stribizhev Wow. That works. Thank you. If you add an answer I could mark it as best answer.

Comment: @SleepySleeper - Where do you mention the relavence of the extended ascii ?

Comment: @sln I mention it in the title. Capital letter AKA elevated ascii? I'm sorry if I was unclear. I don't understand programming lingo almost at all. I can just describe them. I don't know what is the commonly used term.

Comment: @SleepySleeper - Not only didn't you mention it in any way, you just left guessing via an example character class. Since you don't care to elaborate, your question helps nobody. I vote to close this as unclear as to what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `[A-Ö]` matches all lower and uppercase letters and a lot of other symbols, too.

[image]

You need

```
[A-ZÖ][a-zö]+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC9sS4/1)

Note that `+` matches *1 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern*.

Comment: Thank you. I added other letters of the Finnish Alphabet also.                     [A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zöäå]+

Answer (score -2):

```
[A-Ö]{1}[a-ö]*
```

The * means zero or more, if you require a lowercase letter to follow, then use

```
[A-Ö]{1}[a-ö]+
```

Comment: This fixed his problem. Good answer.

Comment: @sln You couldn't be more wrong. Stribizhev did it.

Comment: @SleepySleeper - You said: "`Ab works, but Cmo or Klfdklgklhsh doesn't work. How can I do this?`" This answer `[A-Ö]{1}[a-ö]*` matches `Cmo` and `Klfdklgklhsh`. Nobody is going to try to guess what your problem was. This answer solved it as originally stated. Somebody else edited your original post, not you. If you want to add clarity, don't let someone else do it for you, do it yourself.