# Retrieve Alphabet with white space

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to retrieve the alphabet only but the code is not enough to make it.

What am I missing?

```
[A-Öa-ö]+$

16440 dallas
23941 cityO     < You also have white space after "O"
931 00 Texas
10581 New Orleans
```

Comment: Related: [Regex matching first capital letter followed by one or more small letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986927/regex-matching-first-capital-letter-followed-by-one-or-more-small-letters/33987110#33987110)

Answer (score 7):

It's because you specify a sequence from the ASCII character table. And åäö is not directly after Z in the ascii table.

You can see it here: http://www.asciitable.com/

So what you need is a regex that specifies those separately:

```
[A-Za-zåäöÅÄÖ]+$
```

So the complete regex is:

```
var re = new Regex("([A-Za-zåäöÅÄÖ]+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var matches = re.Matches(data);
Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups[1].Value);
```

However, since you want to allow white spaces within the name (as for "New Orleans") you need to allow it, simply include it in the regex:

```
var re = new Regex("([A-Za-zåäöÅÄÖ ]+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Unfortunately that also includes white spaces in the beginning and the end:

```
" New Orleans "
```

To fix that you start by specifying the regex as greedy, i.e. tell it to use less characters:

```
new Regex("([A-Za-zåäöÅÄÖ ]+?)$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

The problem with that is that it do not take other lines than `New orleans`. Don't ask me why. To fix that I told the regex that it must have a space between the digits and the text and that there may be a space after the text:

```
var re = new Regex("\\s([A-Za-zåäöÅÄÖ ]+?)[\\s]*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

which works with all lines.

Regex breakdown:

- `\\s` A single whitespace *(which should not be included in the match since it's not in the parenthesis expression)*
- `([A-Za-zåäöÅÄÖ ]+?)`

  - Find a character which either is in the alphabet or space
  - `+` there must be one or more
  - `?` use greedy search.
- `[\\s]*`

  - `[\\s]` Find a white space character
  - `*` There must be zero or more if it

**Alternative**

As an alternative to regex you can do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetCodes(string data)
{
    var lines = data.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!char.IsLetter(line[i]))
                continue;

            var text = line.Substring(i).TrimEnd(' ');
            yield return text;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is invoked like:

```
var codes = GetCodes(yourData).ToList();
```

Comment: Maybe I am using it wrong, but for the last line, I only capture "Orleans" using this pattern. Also, what about the whitespace that OP mentions on the "cityO"?

Comment: The data is "23941 cityO   "

Comment: @LarsKristensen: Fixed.

Comment: @jgauffin Wow! Your answer sure has expanded since I first saw it! Great explanations :-) +1

Comment: @KLN: Are you happy with the answer? Or do you need any elaborations?

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can use `\p{L}` Unicode category class to match all Unicode characters. You may match zero or more whitespace characters with `\s*`. End of string is `$` (or `\Z` or `\z`). The word you need can be *captured* and this capture can easily be retrieved from the match result via **[`GroupCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

Thus, you can use

```
(\p{L}+)\s*$
```

or - if you plan to match specific Finnish, etc. letters:

```
(?i)([A-ZÅÄÖ]+)\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B)%5Cs*%24&i=16440%20dallas%0D%0A23941%20cityO%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A931%2000%20Texas%0D%0A10581%20New%20Orleans&o=m)

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/uSkHFg):

```
var strs = new string[] {"16440 dallas", "23941 cityO     ", "931 00 Texas", "10581 New Orleans"};
foreach (var s in strs) {
    var match = Regex.Match(s, @"(\p{L}+)\s*$");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```