# Reqex not starting with white space, only letters can contain white space

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex to check for only letters with posibility to containting white space or `-`.

```
^[a-öA-Ö- ']*$
```

But don't want to allow it to start with white space, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Use `^(?:[a-zöA-ZÖ'-][a-zöA-ZÖ '-]*)?$`. Also, see [Regex matching first capital letter followed by one or more small letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986927/regex-matching-first-capital-letter-followed-by-one-or-more-small-letters/33987110#33987110). What letters other than ASCII do you want to match with your regex?

Comment: `[a-ö]` includes many characters other than letters. Have a look at an ASCII table.

Comment: @Thefourthbird your regex makes little smiley man cry : https://regex101.com/r/Mdi3Bg/1

Comment: @Aaron It is the range the OP used in the example, I just removed the space from the first character class. I will remove the comment. Nice example though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
^(?:[a-zöA-ZÖ'-][a-zöA-ZÖ '-]*)?$
```

Note the main differences:

- `a-ö` and `A-Ö` are replaced with `a-zö` and `A-ZÖ` correspondingly since `a-ö` and `A-Ö` create too big ranges and most probably do not do what you want, see also [Regex matching first capital letter followed by one or more small letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986927/regex-matching-first-capital-letter-followed-by-one-or-more-small-letters/33987110#33987110). Add more after `Ö` and `ö` if necessary.
- The space is taken out of the first character class (that matches 1 char) and added to the second (that matches zero or more chars).

Since your regex matches empty strings, the whole consuming pattern is enclosed with `(?:...)?` optional non-capturing group. If you do not actually want to match empty strings, remove this wrapping:

```
^[a-zöA-ZÖ'-][a-zöA-ZÖ '-]*$
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was what I were looking for ^[a-zöA-ZÖ '-][a-zöA-ZÖ '-]*$